# GPUImage works only on non 64bit simualtors

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, gpu, arm64

I have everything running good on iPhone 4 , 3G, iPad, simulators...howver, when I try to run it on the 64bit iPad or iPhone I get GPUImage errors...do I need to enable something for 64bit arch? thanks

Comment: add arm64 to supported architecture for your target.

Comment: I tried that and still nothing...this is the error I'm getting    get the error in GPUImageVideoCamera.,
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bytesPerRow / 4, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));

-implicit conversion loss integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'GLsizei' (aka 'int')

Comment: can you post the error log here ,  implicit conversion loss integer precision is because you are type casting it i wrong way.

Comment: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'GLsizei' (aka 'int') [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bytesPerRow / 4, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
1 error generated.

Comment: I read other says typecast was wrong...what would I need to do so I Can fix this?

Comment: post code on which line you are getting this error.

Comment: okay send me the link i will check.

Comment: send drop box link here .